# Why should repositories implemented using EF expose IQueryable rather than ObjectQuery?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable, objectquery

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643381/returning-iqueryable-vs-objectquery-when-using-linq-to-entities?rq=1):

> My repositories always returns IQueryable. The reason for this is that
>   IQueryable is not dependent on EF whereas ObjectQuery is. So if I want
>   my other layers to be persistance ignorant I don't want to introduce
>   dependency on ObjectQuery.

a) I assume reason why repositories ( implemented using EF ) should return `IQueryable` instead of `ObjectQuery` is because other ORMs also use queries which return `IQueryable`, and by having repositories return `IQueryable` we can easily switch between EF and other ORMs, without having to change the public interface of a repository?

b) Besides EF and NHibernate, are there any other ORMs that also have queries which return `IQueryable`?

Thank you

Comment: a) Yes b) List<T>.AsQueryable() can be used for testing purposes as well. There is also OData (but it only supports a tiny subset of IQueryable).

Comment: Wake-up call: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/

Answer (score 0):

You should return IQueryable because that's the lingua franca of expression trees. If it's not IQueryable, it's either some other thing that understands Expression, or its some horrible custom language which gives you a greatly inferior programming experience to

var resultsINeed = getQueryable().Where(expression1).Select(expression2);

And if it understands the Expression example here, then it might as well just be IQueryable, because that's the whole *point* of IQueryable - to be that general abstraction, that everybody can reuse in their interfaces.